# How to redirect all pages under WP directory to go back to the homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We had a sloppy web designer who created a new design, they made a /development page on our website by creating a new wordpress install and failed to make it noindex, nofollow so all of our main page is being duplicated in Google under /development.

So I want to redirect all pages found under this directory straight back to the homepage (not strip out only /development)

So this means /development goes to domain.com 
and 
/development/howtofindhelp.html goes to domain.com (homepage) without the extension.

I tried using this and it doesnt seem to work at all, it basically just adds the trailing slash on the end:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^development(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can add below code on functions.php on top .

```
$currernt_url=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if($currernt_url!='your domain'){
     wp_redirect( home_url() );
     exit; 
    }
```

> you can add any url in "your domain"section then it compare with this url except "your domain " it will redirect to home page. you can also use multiple "url" using or Or condition in if condition

Comment: I gave that a try but getting a wp error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/functions.php:5) in /home/public_html/development/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121

Comment: Line 1121 in pluggable.php would be :  header("Location: $location", true, $status);       
        
 return true;

Comment: i have modified some code which will work fine check once

Comment: Thanks for trying but, when adding that code into the functions.php it simply parses the code onto the top left of the website when loading.

Comment: this code working for me. did you add your domain on "your domain" section or goto  the page where you  need to redirect and you can echo the current_url then use that link on "your domain" section

Comment: It still seems to be commenting the same error as before about pluggable.php on line 1121... But the site is loading unlike before.

Comment: instead of functions.php you can also use this code on header.php

Comment: I added it into the header.php this time as $currernt_url=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if($currernt_url!='http://www.mydomain.com.au'){
     wp_redirect( home_url() );
     exit; 
    }

Comment: But the issue still seems to be the same, it simply parses the code into the website screen and doesnt do anything.

Comment: I am also editing the header.php found in the active theme I guess this is correct right?

Comment: ya we need to modify on active theme.

Comment: Also i am curious is using this method a simple redirect or 301 redirect? I am thinking just updating the wp-config setting for the wp_home URL to the main homepage instead of the /development pages.

Comment: I used another method but thanks for the help in trying.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, since I couldnt get the code to work for the header.php I tried something else.

Just edit the wp-config.php and I took off the /development so its just the main homepage. By default when you try to load the page it will jsut say not found. But you can install the 404 to 301 plugin which will redirect all 404 pages.

Since this /development is on its own wordpress install I am fine with it redirecting automatically since the main wordpress install wont have this plugin.